# Excel Formula to aggregate data columns

Tags: excel, sorting, formula, multiple-columns

I am trying to use excel to aggregate some data.

Please look at the below column

[image]

What i would like to do is have 2 columns where Column + Column-A, Column + Column-B, Column + Column-C and if any of the Column-A, Column-B or Column-C is empty, then just ignore that line altogether.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `=A2 & B2`?

Comment: You can use `Concatenate`, `Concat`, `Textjoin`, concatenate operator. Did you tried any of these?

Comment: Plenty of examples as to **UNPIVOT** on this forum. Which have you tried and what problems did you run into?

Comment: What do you expect for results where the cells are not empty but contain only a hyphen, as in your example?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `Concatenate` function?

I would put a `Concatenate` function nested into an `if`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

=IF(AND(ISBLANK(B2)=FALSE,ISBLANK(D2)=FALSE,ISBLANK(F2)=FALSE),A2&C2,"none")